# HttpResponse unable to print the contents of the dictionary

Tags: django, django-views

I am able to print the contents of B dictionary in the command line but When I pass B in the HttpResponse(B), it only shows the keys of the dictionary. I want the content of dictionary to be printed on the template. But unable to do so. How can I achieve this?

Here is my View.py file

```
def A(request):
    B = db_query()       # B is of type 'dict'
    print B              # prints the whole dictionary content with key and value pairs in the command line.
    return HttpResponse(B)       #only prints the key in the template. Why?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only prints the keys because the default iterator for dictionaries returns only keys.

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for i in d:
...    print i
...
a
b
```

In your template, you need to iterate over the keys and the values:

```
{% for k,v in var.iteritems %}
    {{ k }}:{{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```

You also need to use any of the template rendering functions and not `HttpResponse`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def A(request):
   b = db_query()
   return render(request, 'template.html', {'var': b})
```